# Finding adjacent cells in a wraparound matrix

Tags: python, matrix

Say you have an NxM dimensional matrix. For example, a 4x4 matrix:

```
0  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15
```

Each cell has eight adjacent cells.
For example, cell 5's adjacent cells are: 0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10.

```
0 1 2
4 5 6
8 9 10
```

But adjacent cells can also be found by wrapping around the matrix, so cell 7's adjacent cells are 2,3,0,5,4,10,11,8

```
2  3 | 0
6  7 | 4
10 11| 8
```

You can similarly wrap around the top and bottom.

If you pick a point at random (p), is there a simple way to find the values of all eight adjacent cells?
So far, I came up with this list, where m is the width of the matrix (4 in our case).

```
adjacentcells = [p+1, p-1, p+m, p-m, p+m-1, p+m+1, p-m-1, p-m+1]
for value in adjacentcells:
    if value < 0:
        value = value + len(matrix)
    if value >= len(matrix)
        value = value % len(matrix)
    adjacentlist.append(value)
```

However, when you pick a cell in the corner, this returns 7 correct adjacent values, and one errant cell. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

*For complicated (dumb) reasons, I'm storing the matrix as a string, which is why I can do len(matrix) and get 16.

Comment: What does `m` represent?

Comment: Also, which seven neighbors are found correctly and which one isn't?

Comment: @Code-Guru m is the width of the matrix (n is the height). The incorrect adjacent square varies based on which edge out point p sits on.

Comment: Can you give one or two examples to illustrate when the incorrect result occurs?

Comment: `p==15` yields `[0, 14, 3, 11, 2, 4, 10, 12]`, should yield `[0, 14, 3, 11, 2, 8, 10, 12]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use modulo arithmetic on both axes independently, not just on the computed index.

Try using this helper function:

```
def addr(x,y,m,n):
  """
  Given an MxN matrix stored in a 1-d sequence,
  return the index of (possibly wrapped) X,Y
  """
  return (y%n)*m+(x%m)
```

Now you can compute the adjacent cells:

```
def getAdjacentCells(x,y):
  adjacentlist = []
  for dx in (-1, 0, +1):
    for dy in (-1, 0, +1):
      if(dx != 0 or dy != 0):
        adjacentlist.append(addr(x+dx, y+dy, 4, 4))
  return adjacentlist
```

And, you can prove that it works:

```
# 5
assert sorted(getAdjacentCells(1,1)) == [0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10]
# 7
assert sorted(getAdjacentCells(3,1)) == [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11]
# 15
assert sorted(getAdjacentCells(3,3)) == [0, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14]
```